# Check a certain data from a column

Tags: php, mysql

is possible to check a certain data from a column ?
for exemple, I have a column called `'added'` and values is something like `'2011-04-18 10:44:42'`

and is possible to check from column only the date `'2011-04-18'`

```
$date = sqlesc(get_date_time());
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE added = 
        $date ORDER BY username") or print(mysql_error());
```

Comment: what is the datatype of column `added`?

Comment: read :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  id, username
FROM    users
WHERE   added >= '2011-04-18'
        AND added < '2011-04-18' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: i don't think this is as efficient as MYSQL DATE_FORMAT()?

Comment: @wired00: you think right. It's not *as* efficient, it is *more* efficient than `DATE_FORMAT`, since it's sargable (able to use an index on `added`), while `DATE_FORMAT` is not.

Comment: thanks Quassnoi learn something everyday i actually never use date formatting in mysql usually format with php before the query runs

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution... works for DATETIME and all text type fields (such as VARCHAR, TEXT, etc).

```
$date = sqlesc(get_date_time());
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE added LIKE '$date %' 
                    ORDER BY username") or print(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly you need [mysql DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) It will allow formatting your database date value to format of `YYYY-MM-DD`

use something like :

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(added, '%Y-%c-%d') = 
        $date ORDER BY username") or print(mysql_error());
```

hope that helps